NetTopologySuite Projection Y coordinate Off
I am having issues projecting from WGS84 to NAD83 Wisconsin Transverse Mercator. The Y coordinates of the newly projected geometry always end up being a few centimeters north of where they should be and as a result it's creating many slivers on our map application. No issues with the X coordinates.
I'm using NetTopologySuite 2.2.0.
string EPSG4326 = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]";

string EPSG3071 = "PROJCS[\"NAD83(HARN) / Wisconsin Transverse Mercator\",GEOGCS[\"NAD83(HARN)\",DATUM[\"NAD83_High_Accuracy_Regional_Network\",SPHEROID[\"GRS 1980\",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"7019\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6152\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\",0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4152\"]],UNIT[\"metre\",1,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9001\"]],PROJECTION[\"Transverse_Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"latitude_of_origin\",0],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",-90],PARAMETER[\"scale_factor\",0.9996],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",520000],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",-4480000],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"3071\"],AXIS[\"X\",EAST],AXIS[\"Y\",NORTH]]";

var SourceCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(EPSG4326);

var TargetCoordSystem = new CoordinateSystemFactory().CreateFromWkt(EPSG3071);

var trans = new CoordinateTransformationFactory().CreateFromCoordinateSystems(SourceCoordSystem, TargetCoordSystem);

geometry.Apply(new MathTransformFilter(mathTransform));

I confirmed that source and target coordinate systems are correct.
